# Android Async Task does not update UI when application is in background

Tags: android-activity, android-asynctask, android, android-background

The application I am working on downloads and parses a large xml file to populate UI elements, namely search and a spinner. This is done through an async task. If the user decides to switch out of the application during this, the information is downloaded correctly, but then when the application is resumed, the UI will not be updated.

Is this because the changes can't be made while the application is not active? What is the best way to go about checking whether the UI was not updated on resume? Or instead should I be doing something with the Async task, checking whether the UI thread is available? I'm having a hard time debugging this because it involves leaving the application which ends the debugger.

Comment: Add your code, make sure the data are available using log.

Comment: May be Your app goes in Pause mode...!!!

Comment: Try savedinstance state.

Comment: See: http://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html

Comment: It doesn't matter whether your activity is visible or not, async task always update UI. Post some code

Comment: Turns out my problem was due to a check I thought I removed from an old version for controlling my UI elements. Doh. Thanks everyone for the help regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this scenario through the broadcast receive.

Follow the step:

## Solution 1:

Step 1;
Register the broadcast receiver before executing the Asyntask.

Step 2:
send Broadcast in onPostExecute method of Asyntask.

step 3:
And then you can able receive your broadcast message in your activity.
and do whatever you want.

## Solution 2:

Otherwise you can use Interface Call back for this Scenario.

Hope It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It *should'nt*. App being in background means `View` objects may or may not be there. Actually the entire process may be stopped or just deleted by android.

Use a `Service` to truly do processing in background. When processing is complete but UI is not there, post a notification to let user know, OR, save the results and provide it to UI the next time it binds to your service and ask for same thing (a.k.a caching).

Answer (score 0):

The application in background may not be live. The O.S may destroy it in case of memory constrains.

The trick is to try an alternate logic.

When the application moves from background to foreground  onresume() is called ,you could try saving the data to db and update the content on the resume call.

FYI.onPause() and OnResume() is called when the application goes background and foreground respectively.